# Java Stax Iterator API method implementation

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, stax

I know how to utilize java stax iterator api's to read an xml document, but i would like to understand the implementation of XMLEvent and XMLEventReader.

```
XMLInputFactory xmlInFactory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(inFileName);
XMLEventReader xmlEventReader = xmlInFactory.createXMLEventReader(inStream);
while(xmlEventReader.hasNext()){            
    xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
    if(xmlEvent.isStartElement()){              
            startElement = xmlEvent.asStartElement();
            ---more code---
     }
}
```

As both XMLEventReader & XMLEvent are interfaces, where is the implementation for hasNext(), isStartElement() & asStartElement() methods? How are these methods working without method implementation in JDK? Where is this logic coming from?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As these are interfaces, there can be multiple implementations. For example in my development environment I have several implementations of XMLEventReader available, including for example:

- com.sun.xml.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl
- org.codehaus.stax2.XMLEventReader2

The first of these is the Sun pull XML parser, which is distributed in the JDK; the second is part of the third-party Woodstox parser.